# Find max value in pl/sql where there are 2 values that are max

Tags: sql, max

I am using oracle sql developer and I was wondering how you can query the max value of a column where the column has two values that are the max?

For example:

**Shapes**
square
square
square
triangle
circle
circle
circle

when i do select max(shapes), it only gives square but not circle even though both is the max.

Comment: The maximum of what? A string? Are there measurements also in another column?

Comment: there are numbers but converted using to_char

Comment: There is a disconnect with what you want. If there are two identical maximum values then that is still the maximum even if it is not unique. Maybe your query is 'what shapes share the maximum value?'. You must first formulate the question accurately before it is possible to answer it.

Comment: i want to find all the maximums but it is only showing one of them

Answer (score 0):

May not the best way, but u can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT a.*, 
               Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY shapes ORDER BY sm DESC) rnk 
        FROM   (SELECT shapes, 
                       SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY shapes ORDER BY shapes) sm 
                FROM   shapes_table) a) 
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Shapes from TableName
group by Shapes
having COUNT(*) = (
select top 1 COUNT(*) from TableName
group by Shapes order by Shapes desc)
```

This query will give all shapes repeating in that table for maximum times. (This is what I got from your question..)